# Classifying space of semi-direct product of Lie groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, principal-bundles

Let $G$ and $H$ be Lie groups and let $G\rtimes H$ be the product $G\times H$ with group structure given by $$(g_1,h_1)\cdot (g_2,h_2)=(g_1\cdot(h_1g_2),h_1h_2)$$ (i.e. the semi-direct product group). Why is $EH\times_H BG$ a model for $B(G\rtimes H)$?

Comment: Have you considered to view these spaces as geometric bar constructions and then compare these constructions (treated in J.P. May - Classifying spaces and fibrations, chapter 7)? We have that $BG\times_H EH = B_\bullet(BG,H,*)$ and $B(G\rtimes H) = B_\bullet(*,G\rtimes H, *)$. I don't know if this is helpful, but this is the first thought that came to my mind.

Answer (score 3):

The comment is a good one, but there may be an easier way to see it. Find an $E(G \rtimes H)$; then to get $B(G \rtimes H)$, you mod out by the action of $G \rtimes H$. To do this, you can first mod out by the $G$-action; at this point you have a model $E(G \rtimes H)/G$ for $BG$. By construction, the $H$-action is free, so the further quotient by $H$ is homotopy equivalent to $\big(E(G \rtimes H)/G\big) \times_H EH$, essentially by definition. Now you can write this as $BG \times_H EH$, although this doesn't explicitly say what the action of $H$ on $BG$ was. When you expand it out, though, say in the Milnor model for $E(G \rtimes H)$, it is certainly going to turn out to be induced by the conjugation action of $H$ on $G$.